# error:attempt to read or write outside of disk "hdo". grub rescue<

Tags: grubrescue

New PC, set up Win 7, removed Win 7 to install Ubuntu 13.04, installed fine. Once the disk is removed, at boot up It gives error:attempt to read or write outside of disk "hdo". grub rescue< What needs to be done. thx

Comment: Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. Use that from a live CD and put the paste output into your post if it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me where a new install or grub repair would work and reboot, but the next time I rebooted, it would get this same "attempt to read error". Most times I would get a kernel panic and the computer would need a hard restart.

I followed some advice and did a new install using the advanced options (don't use the "erase disk and install ubuntu") using these partition settings:

1. Create a 1 GB (1024 MB) ext4 partition on the beginning of the disk; mounted in "/boot"
2. Create your desired install space in ext4 mounted in "/" MINUS your swap area
3. Use remaining space for swap at the end of the drive.
4. In the boot install drop-down menu, select your "/boot" partition. Not the defaulted drive root!